# How to refer to a specific property from a property in json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have the following json properties schema:

```
"name": {
  "$id": "#/properties/name",
  "type": "string",
  "title": "Name",
  "description": "The name of entity within the network.",
  "default": "",
  "examples": [
    "name-csc1"
  ]
},
"alias": {
  "$id": "#/properties/alias",
  "type": "string",
  "title": "Alias",
  "description": "The custom name, alias, set by the user in the network.",
  "default": "",
  "examples": [
    "Updated-Name111"
  ]
```

I want to refer to the default field of the `alias` property to the `name` property since the default value of `alias` field is the `name` value.

Is there a way to do that in json schema?

Comment: No, you can't do that with JSON Schema. You can't reference the instance data from a schema. Even within a schema you can only reference a schema,

Comment: @JasonDesrosiers So what would be the best way to let the user know this correlation?

Comment: That would depend on who your users are and if they are looking at the schemas or not.